# Search for name(text) with spaces in elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, tokenize, analyzer

Searching for names(text) with spaces in it, causing problem to me, 
I have mapping similar to

```
"{"user":{"properties":{"name":{"type":"string"}}}}"
```

Ideally what it should return and rank results as follows

```
1) Bring on top names that exact match the search term (highest score)
2) Names that starts with the search term (high score)
3) Names that contains the exact search term as substring (medium score)
4) Names that contains any of the search term token  (lowest score)
```

Example 
For following names in elasticsearch

```
Maaz Tariq
Ahmed Maaz Tariq
Maaz Sheeba
Maaz Bin Tariq
Sana Tariq
Maaz Tariq Ahmed
```

Searching for "Maaz Tariq" , Results should be in following order

```
Maaz Tariq (highest score)
Maaz Tariq Ahmed (high score)
Ahmed Maaz Tariq (medium score)
Maaz Bin Tariq  (lowest score)
Maaz Sheeba (lowest score)
Sana Tariq (lowest score)
```

Can any one point me how and which analyzers to use? and how to rank the search results for names?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [multi field type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type/), a [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query/) and the [custom boost factor query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-boost-factor-query/) to solve this problem.

Mapping:

```
{
    "mappings" : {
        "user" : {        
            "properties" : {
                "name": {
                    "type": "multi_field",
                    "fields": {
                        "name": { "type" : "string", "index": "analyzed" },
                        "exact": { "type" : "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "Maaz Tariq"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "custom_boost_factor": {
                        "query": {
                            "term": {
                                "name.exact": "Maaz Tariq"
                            }
                        },
                        "boost_factor": 15
                    }
                },
                {
                    "custom_boost_factor": {
                        "query": {
                            "prefix": {
                                "name.exact": "Maaz Tariq"
                            }
                        },
                        "boost_factor": 10
                    }
                },
                {
                    "custom_boost_factor": {
                        "query": {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "name": {
                                    "query": "Maaz Tariq",
                                    "slop": 0
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "boost_factor": 5
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**edit:**

As pointed out by javanna, the `custom_boost_factor` isn't needed.

Query without `custom_boost_factor`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "Maaz Tariq"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "name.exact": {
                            "value": "Maaz Tariq",
                            "boost": 15
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "name.exact": {
                            "value": "Maaz Tariq",
                            "boost": 10
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "name": {
                            "query": "Maaz Tariq",
                            "slop": 0,
                            "boost": 5
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer a filter based solution but I couldn't found the right filter for the 3. requirement.

Comment: You can just make a phrase query for that. Also, I don't get why you need a custom_boost_factor query. Can't you just give a different weight to your different queries using the `boost` option?

Comment: `Boost` isn't allowed in a `should` sub query!? (At least I don't know the syntax for this.) And how does a phrase query filter work without the `span_near` query and without the `match_phrase` query?

Comment: As far as I remember every query supports the boost. Actually, the phrase query is what you are doing with match_phrase, didn't realize that!

Comment: I tried it. If I add a `boost` to the sub query it becomes invalid.

Comment: You might be doing something wrong then I'm afraid. Have a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/imotov/b62f45dcf28a5c030e67 .

Comment: You are right, thanks. My mistake was that I used `query` instead of `value` in the term query.

Comment: @Ivaldi : great stuffbro.. it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

In case of Java Api, when quering exact strings with spaces use;

```
CLIENT.prepareSearch(index)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(wordString)
    .field(fieldName));
```

In a lot of other queries, you get nothing as result

Answer (score 0):

And from Elasticsearch 1.0:

```
"title": {
    "type": "multi_field",
    "fields": {
        "title": { "type": "string" },
        "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
    }
}
```

became:

```
"title": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
        "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html